# Crosswords in Mathematica using Pattern Matching

Tags: pattern-matching, wolfram-mathematica, crossword

Suppose I select all 3 char words from the Mathematica dictionary:

```
all3 = Characters /@ Select[DictionaryLookup[], StringLength[#] == 3 &];
```

and I want to form full scrabble-like sets, like:

```
A B E
R A Y
E R E
```

Where the words can be read horizontally and vertically.

Clearly, the sets can be found with recursion and backtracking. But:

1) Is there a way to solve it using patterns?
2) For which dimensions are there valid solutions?

**Edit**

I wrote the question for `DictionaryLookup[]` just because it's a reasonable sized database of variable length records. My real problem is not related to Dictionary lookups but to a certain kind of loom patterns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure if you would consider the following approach pattern based -- but it works, and it can conceivably be extended to many dimensions, although with the `all3` dataset, it would probably konk out rather early...

The idea is to start with a blank crossword:

```
blankCW={{_,_,_},{_,_,_},{_,_,_}};
```

and then recursively do the following: For a given pattern, look at the rows in turn and (after filling out any with exactly one completion) expand the pattern on the row with the fewest number of matches:

```
(* Cache the number of matches for a given pattern *)
nmatch[patt_]:=nmatch[Verbatim@patt]=Length@Cases[all3,patt]

(* A helper to fill single matches if needed *)
fixone[ml_,nl_]:=If[FreeQ[ml[[nl]],Verbatim[_]],ml, 
  ReplacePart[ml, nl->First@Cases[all3,ml[[nl]]]]];

findCompletions[m_]:=Module[{nn,ur},
  (* Pattern w/ filled single matches -> ur, ordering by # of matches -> nn *)
  {ur,nn}=NestWhile[{fixone[#[[1]],First@#[[2]]], Rest@#[[2]]}&,
    {m,Ordering[nmatch/@m]},
    (Length[#[[2]]]>0&&nmatch@#[[1,#[[2,1]]]]==1)&];

  (* Expand on the word with the fewest number og matches *)
  If[Length[nn]==0,{ur},
    With[{n=First@nn},ReplacePart[ur,n-> #]&/@Cases[all3,ur[[n]]]]]];
```

For a given candidate pattern, try out the completion along both dimensions and keep the one that yield the fewest:

```
findCompletionsOriented[m_]:=Module[{osc},
  osc=findCompletions/@Union[{m,Transpose@m}];
  osc[[First@Ordering[Length/@osc,1]]]]
```

I do the recursion breadth first to be able to use Union, but depth first might be necessary for bigger problems. Performance is so-so: 8 laptop minutes to find the 116568 matches in the example problem:

```
Timing[crosswords=FixedPoint[Union[Join@@(findCompletionsOriented/@#)]&,{blankCW}];]
Length@crosswords
TableForm/@Take[crosswords,5]

Out[83]= {472.909,Null}
Out[84]= 116568
          aah aah aah aah aah
Out[86]={ ace ace ace ace ace }
          hem hen hep her hes
```

In principle, it should be possible to recurse this into higher dimensions, i.e. using the crosswords list instead of the wordlist for dimension 3. If the time to match a pattern against a list is linear in the list-length, this would be quite slow with a 100000+ sized wordlist...

Comment: @Janus Nice! Is there an easy way to cut off the number of solutions to find? I want to do a test drive for higher dimensions, but I'd like to evaluate how long it may take first :)

Comment: @belisarius: Maybe the simplest is to truncate the wordlist as Yaroslav does? Also, watch out for the size of the nmatch cache: you will run out of space at some point :)

Comment: @Janus The problem with that approach is that I'll not get easily the idea of what will happen with the full set. Will try, though. Thanks!

Comment: @belisarius: Thinking about it, I actually think that for higher dimensions, it is too expensive to count matches: Just fill one of the most constrained words, depth first. With a fast `FindFirstMatchAfter` implementation, this might actually work...

Comment: @belisarius. Another reduced version might be to truncate the result list after each step in the fixed point search. `(Take[#,Min[Length@#,1000]]&)@Union[...` instead of just `Union` in the call to `FixedPoint`.

Comment: @Janus I guess you may try to answer this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086872/is-it-possible-to-shuffle-a-2d-matrix-while-preserving-row-and-column-frequencies with a variation of your algorithm

Comment: @Janus, @belisarius -- matlab had a crossword contest recently along these lines -- http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/contest/contests/32/rules

Answer (score 8):

An alternative approach is to use `SatisfiabilityInstances` with constraints specifying that every row and every column must be a valid word. Code below takes 40 seconds to get first 5 solutions using dictionary of 200 three-letter words. You could replace `SatisfiabilityInstances` with `SatisfiabilityCount` to get the number of such crosswords.

```
setupCrossword[wordStrings_] := (
   m = Length[chars];

   words = Characters /@ wordStrings;
   chars = Union@Flatten@words;

   wordMatch[vars_, word_] := And @@ (Thread[{vars, word}]);
   validWord[vars_] := Or @@ (wordMatch[vars, #] & /@ words);
   validCell[{i_, j_}] := 
    BooleanCountingFunction[{1}, {{i, j}, #} & /@ chars];

   row[i_] := {i, #} & /@ Range[n];
   col[i_] := {#, i} & /@ Range[n];
   cells = Flatten[row /@ Range[n], 1];

   rowCons = validWord[row[#]] & /@ Range[n];
   colCons = validWord[col[#]] & /@ Range[n];
   cellCons = validCell /@ cells;
   formula = And @@ (Join[rowCons, colCons, cellCons]);
   vars = 
    Table[{{i, j}, c}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {c, chars}] // 
     Flatten[#, 2] &;
   decodeInstance[instance_] := (
     choices = Extract[vars, Position[instance, True]];
     grid = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] /. Rule @@@ choices
     )
   );

n = 3;
wordLimit = 200;
wordStrings = 
  Select[DictionaryLookup[], 
   StringLength[#] == n && LowerCaseQ[#] &];
setupCrossword[wordStrings[[;; wordLimit]]];

vals = SatisfiabilityInstances[formula, vars, 5];
Framed@TableForm@decodeInstance@# & /@ vals
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/crosswords.png))</sub>

This approach uses variables like `{{i,j},"c"}` to indicate the cell `{i,j}` gets letter "c". Each cell is constrained get exactly one letter with `BooleanCountingFunction`, every row and column is constrained to make a valid word. For instance, constraint that first row must be either "ace" or "bar" looks like this

```
{{1,1},"a"}&&{{1,2},"c"}&&{{1,3},"e"}||{{1,1},"b"}&&{{1,2},"a"}&&{{1,3},"r"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I never used **SatisfiabilityInstances** before, although I saw you used it in those nice tetrahedron problems you used to post. I guess this one will take a me some time to chew :D

Comment: Nice idea! I think the pattern matching is a dead end: even with dispatch tables I couldn't check more than a million candidates per second -- which would mean more than an hour for the whole problem.

Comment: @Janus @Yaro Using this one, for four chars words,  the first solution takes 11 minutes. BTW it contains the word **burp**

Comment: The solution is nice and I learned a lot from it. However the time complexity of the algorithm seems too high to be practical for my purposes (dimension 8 to 10)