# Enumerate matrix combinations with fixed row and column sums

Tags: algorithm, matrix, combinations, enumeration, counting

I'm attempting to find an algorithm (not a matlab command) to enumerate all possible NxM matrices with the constraints of having only positive integers in each cell (or 0) and fixed sums for each row and column (these are the parameters of the algorithm).

Exemple :
Enumerate all 2x3 matrices with row totals 2, 1 and column totals 0, 1, 2:

```
| 0 0 2 | = 2
| 0 1 0 | = 1
  0 1 2

| 0 1 1 | = 2
| 0 0 1 | = 1
  0 1 2
```

This is a rather simple example, but as N and M increase, as well as the sums, there can be a lot of possibilities.

---

Edit 1

I might have a valid arrangement to start the algorithm:

```
matrix = new Matrix(N, M) // NxM matrix filled with 0s
FOR i FROM 0 TO matrix.rows().count()
  FOR j FROM 0 TO matrix.columns().count()
    a = target_row_sum[i] - matrix.rows[i].sum()
    b = target_column_sum[j] - matrix.columns[j].sum()
    matrix[i, j] = min(a, b)
  END FOR
END FOR
```

target_row_sum[i] being the expected sum on row i.

In the example above it gives the 2nd arrangement.

---

Edit 2:
(based on [j_random_hacker's last statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17885398/547733))

Let M be any matrix verifying the given conditions (row and column sums fixed, positive or null cell values).
Let (a, b, c, d) be 4 cell values in M where (a, b) and (c, d) are on the same row, and (a, c) and (b, d) are on the same column.
Let Xa be the row number of the cell containing a and Ya be its column number.

Example:

```
| 1 a b |
| 1 2 3 |
| 1 c d |
-> Xa = 0, Ya = 1
-> Xb = 0, Yb = 2
-> Xc = 2, Yc = 1
-> Xd = 2, Yd = 2
```

Here is an algorithm to get all the combinations verifying the initial conditions and making only a, b, c and d varying:

```
// A matrix array containing a single element, M
// It will be filled with all possible combinations
matrices = [M]

I = min(a, d)
J = min(b, c)
FOR i FROM 1 TO I
    tmp_matrix = M
    tmp_matrix[Xa, Ya] = a - i
    tmp_matrix[Xb, Yb] = b + i
    tmp_matrix[Xc, Yc] = c - i
    tmp_matrix[Xd, Yd] = d + i
    matrices.add(tmp_matrix)
END FOR
FOR j FROM 1 TO J
    tmp_matrix = M
    tmp_matrix[Xa, Ya] = a + j
    tmp_matrix[Xb, Yb] = b - j
    tmp_matrix[Xc, Yc] = c + j
    tmp_matrix[Xd, Yd] = d - j
    matrices.add(tmp_matrix)
END FOR
```

It should then be possible to find every possible combination of matrix values:

1. Apply the algorithm on the first matrix for every possible group of 4 cells ;
2. Recursively apply the algorithm on each sub-matrix obtained by the previous iteration, for every possible group of 4 cells except any group already used in a parent execution ;

The recursive depth should be `(N*(N-1)/2)*(M*(M-1)/2)`, each execution resulting in `((N*(N-1)/2)*(M*(M-1)/2) - depth)*(I+J+1)` sub-matrices. But this creates a LOT of duplicate matrices, so this could probably be optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Are you needing this to calculate [Fisher's exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test)?  Because that requires what you're doing, and based on that page, it seems there will in general be a vast number of solutions, so you probably can't do better than a brute force recursive enumeration if you want every solution.  OTOH it seems Monte Carlo approximations are successfully used by some software instead of full-blown enumerations.

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086872/is-it-possible-to-shuffle-a-2d-matrix-while-preserving-row-and-column-frequencie), which might be helpful.  Although that question deals with preserving frequencies of letters in each row and column rather than sums, some results can be translated across.  E.g. if you find any submatrix (pair of not-necessarily-adjacent rows and pair of not-necessarily-adjacent columns) with numbers

```
xy
yx
```

Then you can rearrange these to

```
yx
xy
```

without changing any row or column sums.  However:

- [mhum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5087786/47984) proves that there will in general be valid matrices that cannot be reached by any sequence of such 2x2 swaps.  This can be seen by taking his 3x3 matrices and mapping `A -> 1`, `B -> 2`, `C -> 4` and noticing that, because no element appears more than once in a row or column, frequency preservation in the original matrix is equivalent to sum preservation in the new matrix.  *However...*
- [someone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5091273/47984) links to a mathematical proof that it actually will work for matrices whose entries are just 0 or 1.

More generally, if you have any submatrix

```
ab
cd
```

where the (not necessarily unique) minimum is d, then you can replace this with any of the d+1 matrices

```
ef
gh
```

where h = d-i, g = c+i, f = b+i and e = a-i, for any integer 0 <= i <= d.

Comment: Indeed, I need this algorithm to apply Fisher's Exact test on large data samples (but relatively low cell values, hence excluding any asymptotic test such as the Chi² test).
I also need the algorithm for another problem, more practical, involving many sellers (each with a set of available items in variable quantity) and a buyer trying to find the best configuration given a set of items to buy in different quantities (lowest cost, including fixed and variable fees for each seller and each type of item...) - but I'll take a look at Monte Carlo tests anyway.

Comment: If the row and column sums are low, it might be feasible to enumerate all possibilities by deciding for each row (say) in turn how to distribute indistinguishable "marbles" to "bins", where each cell in the row is a bin and the row sum tells you how many marbles you have. There are `(n+r-1) choose (r-1)` ways of distributing r marbles across n bins for a single row; multiply the result you get for each row together to get a loose upper bound on the number of configurations (loose because some distributions will be outlawed by column sums).

Answer (score 0):

For a NXM matrix you have NXM unknowns and N+M equations. Put random numbers to the top-left (N-1)X(M-1) sub-matrix, except for the (N-1, M-1) element. Now, you can find the closed form for the rest of N+M elements trivially.

More details: There are total of T = N*M elements

There are R = (N-1)+(M-1)-1 randomly filled out elements.

Remaining number of unknowns: T-S = N*M - (N-1)*(M-1) +1 = N+M

Comment: I just edited the question to include an additional constraint: cell values must be positive or null integers, otherwise there would be an infinite number of arrangements and your proposition would indeed be the only valid answer.